# Vue how to display the edit button only when a field in a table is false

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, vuex

I have a table with users' holidays and I would like the edit button to appear only when the confirmed field is false. And when vacation is already confirmed then button should not be visible

Vacation request table **:**

[image]

Here is my template with vacation table:

```
<template>
<v-card>
    <v-data-table :items="vacations" :items-per-page="5" :headers="headers">
        <template v-slot:[`item.action`]="{ item }">
            <v-icon
                small
                class="mr-2"
                @click="editVacation(item)"
                color="primary"
            >
                mdi-pencil
            </v-icon>
            <v-icon
                v-if="isAdmin"
                small
                class="mr-2"
                @click="deleteVacation(item)"
                color="red"
            >
                mdi-delete
            </v-icon>
            <v-icon
                v-if="isAdmin"
                small
                class="mr-2"
                @click="confirmVacation(item)"
                color="green"
            >
                mdi-check
            </v-icon>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
</v-card>
```

And the script:

```
  props: {
        vacations: {
            type: Array,
            required: false,
            defaultValue: () => []
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            showCreateOrEditModal: false,
            headers: [
                {
                    text: 'ID',
                    value: 'id',
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    text: 'User first name',
                    value: 'user.firstName',
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    text: 'User last name',
                    value: 'user.lastName',
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    text: 'Start date',
                    value: 'startDate',
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    text: 'End date',
                    value: 'endDate',
                    sortable: false
                },
                {
                    text: 'Confirmed',
                    value: 'confirmed',
                    sortable: false
                },
                { text: 'Actions', value: 'action', sortable: false }
            ]
        };
    },
    methods: {
        editVacation(vacation) {
            this.$emit('edit-vacation', vacation);
        },

        deleteVacation(vacation) {
            this.$emit('delete-vacation', vacation);
        },

        confirmVacation(vacation) {
            this.$emit('confirm-vacation', vacation);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters({ isAdmin: 'isAdmin' })
       
};
</script>
```

I tried to use v-if and create some function in the computed section, but unfortunately either the button does not display for any of the holidays, or it displays for all

Comment: Did you tried `v-if="!item.confirmed"` in your edit icon element ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try:

```
<v-icon
    v-if="!item.confirmed"
    small
    class="mr-2"
    @click="editVacation(item)"
    color="primary"
>
    mdi-pencil
</v-icon>
```

Adding the `v-if="!item.confirmed"` on the edit button